# Reverse proxy between a unicorn server and Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, reverse-proxy, galera

I want to do an architecture deployment system with Docker.
I have a rails contener with unicorn who communicates with a nginx contener, and I also have two galera clusters on 2 systems.

I want to make the the galeras clusters communicate with the rails application but I don't know which reverse proxy I need.
I've tested  a mysql proxy but i don't know if it is the best solution.

Edit:
I think what the best solution is HAproxy.
http://www.severalnines.com/mysql-load-balancing-haproxy-tutorial

Comment: You have a problem or try to find the best solution?

Comment: I will find the best solution!

Comment: I vote to close this question. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I try lot of solutions but there are no solution optimised for what i will do. I try mysql proxy and HaProxy.